# Parrallel mahalanobis raster classification in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, classification, raster, mahalanobis

I'm looking for the most efficient way to classify raster using **Mahalanobis distance to class**. My classes are already summarised by mean and covariance.

So far, I'm tansfmorming my 6 bands input stacks image as a data frame and I'm then using the `stats::mahalanobis`
I've tried the following solution:

- using `spatial.tools::rasterEngine`
- `raster::clusterR`

Is there a dedicated package or tool for image classification with mahalanobis distance implemented in parallel?
I've about 5000 raster of 8000 by 8000 pixels and the performance is thus critical.
Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: you might want to try http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @maRtin : The gis.stackexchange.com community is much smaller than stackoverflow. Moreover it  doesn't cover 'not spatial' image classification solution thus I prefer to ask it here to have more ideas.